# What are the multiclassing rules for Ultramodern 5 Redux?

Tags: multi-classing, ultramodern5

What are the multiclassing rules for Ultramodern 5 Redux? Since the classes are different than the standard 5e fantasy, I'm not quite certain what gets carried over or not from class to class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Multiclassing rules are found in errata

Neither the Ultramodern 5 or U5 Redux rulebooks include an adequate explanation of how multiclassing works with the new classes they describe, although multiclassing is referenced a few times in the rules so it is clear that it is meant to be possible. However this issue has been addressed in errata.

The "Downloads" link on the [Dias Ex Machina website](https://diasexmachina.com/) goes to a google docs folder in which can be found the [Ultramodern 5 Redux "Patch"](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c7JAugQ84vHAA0XuRcJOItcyT0XUnx7K/view) document, which is basically an errata document by another name. As of the time of posting, the current version is 1.8, published April 2022. This document introduces the missing rules for multiclassing:

> PAGE 58
>
> Multiclassing has not been adequately explained...
>
> Prerequisites. There are no class prerequisites.
>
> Proficiencies. Picking up a class later offers only
> a few additional proficiencies. When selecting an
> additional class, a character gains all armor, weapon,
> and tool proficiencies and can select a number of
> skills based on the number of skills offered by the
> new class. Count the number of skills offered and
> divide by 2 (round down)—this is the number of
> skills from that class you can gain proficiency with
> (player choice).
>
> *For example, selecting a civilian will gain armor,
> weapons, and any two skills, while the grounder will
> offer armor, weapons, tools, and one skill.*